# How can I ssh from my virtual machine to the local host?

Tags: ssh, virtual-machine, virtualization, authentication, localhost

How can I ssh from my virtual machine to the local host?

I need exact details please.

Note:
Virtual machine = Ubuntu 14
Host machine = Ubuntu 16

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Using ssh from your VM to the localhost on your host machine will use the host machine address. Open a terminal on the Host (Ctrl + t) and type 
`ifconfig`

look for something like  inet addr:192.168.XX.XX and then ssh to that address.

Be sure to ensure your host firewall settings are going to allow ssh in from only specified addresses on port 22. Assuming you have ssh set up to listen in its default manner - You can control firewall settings in Ubuntu using the `ufw` command. like this on the Host:

`sudo ufw enable`

`sudo ufw allow proto ssh from 192.168.1.100 to 192.168.1.110 port 22`

Then from your VM for example:

`ssh`host_username`@192.168.1.XX`

*This type of connection happens over the network rather than through a socket on your host machine. In a scenario where you are still unable to ssh to your host machines address, check your LAN router, switch, or firewall to see if it is preventing ssh on your internal network.*

Comment: Ok can you help me how can I disable the password prompt?

Comment: Yes I just ssh'd thank you for helping me. Just one more thing how can I disable the password prompt?

Comment: + is there a way that I can ssh from the virtual private network? virbr0 or something?

Comment: Nevermind I ssh'd cis virbr0 network. Is there any way to not enter the password?

Comment: disabling the password prompt is done via the ssh configuration files.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20898384/ssh-disable-password-authentication

Comment: You may also `sshpass -p 'YourPassword' ssh user@host` to send the password with the ssh login if necessary. 
From: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38737/ssh-login-with-clear-text-password-as-a-parameter

Comment: Optionally: using a password key file is a lot more work, but much more secure than any other options. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys